# Error: Illegal arguments: number at Object.bcrypt.getSalt encrypt - No encripta la contraseña

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, bcryptjs

No comprendo cual puede ser el error, la documentación menciona que el numero minimo para generar el salt es 10 y así lo estoy usando, si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Esta es el codigo que ejecuto al registrar a un usuario.

```js
usersController.singUp = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, confirm_password } = req.body;
    const errors = [];
    let data = { name, email };

    if (password != confirm_password) errors.push({ text: "Passwords no coinciden" });
    if (password.length < 4) errors.push({ text: "El password es menor a 4 caracteres" }); 

    // console.log(req.body);
    // console.log(errors);

    if (errors.length > 0) res.render('users/singup', { errors, data });
    else {
        const emailUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if(emailUser){
            req.flash('error_msg','The email is alredy in use');
            res.redirect('/users/singup');
        } else {
            try {
                let newUser = new User({ name, email, password });

                // Cifraremos la contraseña
                newUser.password = await newUser.encryptPassword(password);
                // Guardamos al usuario
                let result = await newUser.save();
                // console.log(result);
                req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered');
                res.redirect('/users/singin');
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Esta es la ruta que uso para ejecutarla.

```js
router.post('/users/singup', singUp);
```

Y este es el modelo que uso  para usuarios.

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true , unique: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true }
},{ timestamps: true });

// Cifra la comtraseña
userSchema.methods.encryptPassword = async (password) => {
    console.log('antes');

    const salt = await bcrypt.getSalt(10);
    console.log(salt);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    console.log(hash);

    return hash;
}

// Compara la contraseña con la de la bd
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function(password){
    await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

const User = model('User', userSchema);

module.exports= User;
```

Sin embargo, al querer encriptar la contraseña y quererla guardar junto con el nuevo usuario me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya busque el error pero ninguna de las cosas que he encontrado me han servido a solucionarlo y comprender a que se debe el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estuve mirando tu código y me di el permiso de cambiar algunas cosas si no te importa, para ver si de esta manera se puede solucionar tu problema.

(Cambios comentados en el código)

Ejemplo de modelo:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// Genera el HASH de contraseña
const generateHashPassword = plainPassword => {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(plainPassword, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
};

// Modifica la contraseña aplicandole el hash de contraseña
userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  try {
    let user = this;

    if (!user.isModified("password")) {
      return next();
    }

    user.password = generateHashPassword(user.password);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

// Compara la contraseña original con la contraseña "HASEADA"
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, hashPassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hashPassword, function (err, isMatch) {

    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};

module.exports = model("users", userSchema);
```

Ejemplo función crear usuario:

```
usersController.singUp = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, confirm_password } = req.body;
  const errors = [];
  let data = { name, email };

  if (password != confirm_password)
    errors.push({ text: "Passwords no coinciden" });
  if (password.length < 4)
    errors.push({ text: "El password es menor a 4 caracteres" });

  if (errors.length > 0) res.render("users/singup", { errors, data });
  else {
    const emailUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });

    if (emailUser) {
      req.flash("error_msg", "The email is alredy in use");
      res.redirect("/users/singup");
    } else {
      // creas el usuario directamente
      User.create(req.body)
        .then(() => {
          req.flash("success_msg", "You are registered");
          res.redirect("/users/singin");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, si me sirvio, se corrigio el problema !!

Answer (score 0):

El error Error: Illegal arguments: number le corregí utilizando **genSaltSync(10)**  envez del <strike>genSalt(10)</strike>. genSal("texto?") parece que solo acepta texto

Answer (score 0):

genSaltSync(10) funcion bien! gracias por el aporte Sebastián,

recomiendo usar tambien hashSync
ejm:
const salt = await bcryptjs.genSaltSync(10);

const HashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hashSync(password,salt);

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás realizar comentarios, mientras tanto abstente de usar esta sección con publicaciones que no tengan como fin responder a la pregunta. Para mas información te invito a que visites las secciones de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para más información.